# Simple image url not displayed on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native

I can't figure out why the image from the following address doesn't display on React Native:

Url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/desire-app-e9e94.appspot.com/o/profile%2Fguest-user.webp?alt=media&token=fe99fdf9-d36a-4548-b295-cc2fdce79f64

The url is generated through the firebase storage function, if url is entered in the browser it is displayed correctly, but I don't understand why it is not displayed inside the image component

My code:

```
<Image
      source={{
        uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/desire-app-e9e94.appspot.com/o/profile%2Fdefault_user.svg?alt=media&token=cd6fed4a-86da-4c52-bad7-7f8f0d83fd3a',
      }}
      style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
/>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: You cannot display SVGs using `<Image />`. You need to install a package to do that, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg

Comment: And it's the same for webp as well. You have to use a package to support webp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **webp** package for display webp images.

Run these below 2 commands, then after you should be able to display the images.

```
npm install --save react-native-webp

react-native link react-native-webp
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Image
      source={{
        uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/desire-app-e9e94.appspot.com/o/profile%2Fdefault_user.svg?alt=media&token=cd6fed4a-86da-4c52-bad7-7f8f0d83fd3a',
      }}
      style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
/>
```

The url which you kept in this source is not same as what you mentioned, your url is incorrect in <Image tag,  copy and paste the url correctly and your image will display,

try this,

```html
 <Image
      source={{
        uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/desire-app-e9e94.appspot.com/o/profile%2Fguest-user.webp?alt=media&token=fe99fdf9-d36a-4548-b295-cc2fdce79f64',
      }}
      style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
/>
```